# how to define jenkins plugin folder as persistence volume in stable/jenkins helm chart

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes-helm

I'm using the [stable helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins) in order to deploy it in my OCP environment.

I activate the persistence volume where jenkins save the **jenkins_home** folder.

I found that the helm chart define the plugin and plugin-dir folder as empty volume folder.

It's cause to download the plugins every time when pod is restarted.

How can I configure it that plugin dir will be also configured as persistence volume?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in [this](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/jenkins/templates/config.yaml#L182) line.

The default [value](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/jenkins/values.yaml#L222) for the `overwritePlugins` variable is `true`.

This means that if you do not explicitly set it to `false`, the `ConfigMap` that will be generated will create the following line, in an inline script to be executed

```
rm -rf /var/jenkins_home/plugins/*
```

Then, and assuming you have elements in the `installPlugins` [list](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/jenkins/values.yaml#L214), it will proceed with (re-downloading) and installing those plugins.

Keep in mind that it seems that **AFTER** installation, plugins seem to end up to `/var/jenkins_home/plugins` that (assuming you have set a PVC) is a persistent location.